# Time reversal invariance and statistics

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, spin-statistics, time-reversal-symmetry, cpt-symmetry

To what extend does the behaviour of time reversal invariance depend on 
the statistics of the particle under consideration? 
More explicitly: To what extend does the action of the time reversal operator 
depend on the commutation relations of say fermions, bosons, etc.?

Given a certain Hilbert space (say $\mathbb{C}^N$) with $N>2$ (so we are not 
talking Spin 1/2). What is the general way to construct a Time reversal symmetry
operator?

I am looking forward to your response.